# How do I pass a Controller (controllername) as parameter to another method?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core

so I'm wondering if it's possible to send a Controller as a parameter to another method. What I'm trying to acomplish is to create a method that acts like a Filepath builder by taking two parameters (controllername and method name).

I have a method in a Controller as shown below:

```
  public async Task GetActiveCountyRegulationByIdSuccess()
    {

        FilePathBuilder builder = new FilePathBuilder();
        builder.FilePath(CountyControllerTest,GetActiveCountyRegulationByIdSuccess);
        ...
```

So the name of my controller is CountyControllerTest and the name of my method is GetActiveCountyRegulationByIdSuccess. I want to send those two parameters to:

```
 public class FilePathBuilder
   {

    public string FilePath(object controller, object method)
       {
        var filePath = "testfiles/" + nameof(controller) + nameof(method) + "Actual.xml";

        return filePath;
       }
   }
```

And return the string beeing built in the FilePath Method back to my controller. Problem is that I get an error in my controller when I try passing it as a parameter. The error message sais that 'CountyController' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: You can use the `[CallMemberName]` attribute to inject the action's name into a string parameter. Check [Caller INformation (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information#member-names)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for two properties:

```
  var action = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
  var controller = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass my controller and method by simply:

```
FilePathBuilder builder = new FilePathBuilder();
builder.FilePath(nameof(CountyControllerTest), nameof(GetActiveCountyRegulationByIdSuccess));
```

And in my FilePath method:

```
public class FilePathBuilder
{

    public string FilePath(object controller, object method)
    {
        var filePath = "TestFiles/" + controller + "/" + method + "Actual.xml";

        return filePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to ask why didn't you start from that? You can get rid of the action name at least with the `[CallMemberName]` attribute

Comment: I didn't think of it, I don't use nameof that often.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with System.Reflection:

```
// Current class name
this.GetType().Name
// Current method name 
MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
```

Please note that the Recflection usage is relatively slow/costly operation, maybe it's better to stick with string constants..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are not passing a class instance. What you could do is change your method such that it accepts a type and from there you can can the class name. Like this:

```
  public async Task GetActiveCountyRegulationByIdSuccess()
    {

        FilePathBuilder builder = new FilePathBuilder();
        builder.FilePath(typeof(CountyControllerTest), typeof(GetActiveCountyRegulationByIdSuccess));
        ...
```

And the builder method then accepts 2 type parameters and uses their names:

```
public class FilePathBuilder
   {

    public string FilePath(Type controllerType, Type methodType)
       {
        var filePath = "testfiles/" + controllerType.Name  + methodType.Name + "Actual.xml";

        return filePath;
       }
   }
```